# listview sqlite "ListAdapter"

Tags: listview, listitem

I have to finish a listview, I'm stuck, can someone help me?
I am a beginner, I can not understand "ListAdapter"

thanks

```
private void lista(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = new MioDbHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT nome_utente_pc, password_pc, note_pc FROM Password";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dettaglio_lista_pc){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView tvUtente, tvPass, tvNote;
            tvUtente = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_utente_pc);


            tvPass = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_password_pc);

            tvNote = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_note_pc);

        }
    };
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Comment: what exactly is that you can't understand about ListAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you spend some time while reading the APIs for listView and sample example given in Developer site. You can also refer Vogella codebase examples for basic implementation and good understanding.[Vogella tutorials page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/) Here is the link:
[Android developer page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/)

Comment: I can not set the cursor to insert values ​​in TextView.
Can you explain me

Comment: Follow this link. It will help. Try with a small POC to check the APIs.                                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330565/using-cursor-with-listview-adapter-for-a-large-amount-of-data