# CursorAdapter changeCursor bolck ui thread in android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

My program use a CursorAdapter for my GridView , and use AsynTask to get curosr and refresh my view.

In task's doinbackgroud ,I excute a query in sqlite , and get the cursor.
In task's onPostExecute , I use CursorAdapter.changeCursor to refresh my view by new data.

But ui thread was blocked when changeCursor because the cursor has too many data about thousands rows.

Doesn't the cursor use the lasy strategy?
How should I do?

my code:

```
private class ToNodeTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void , OrgManager.CursorDataInfoInStruct >{

    protected Long taskId = null;

    @Override
    protected  OrgManager.CursorDataInfoInStruct doInBackground(Long... params) {
        taskId = params[0];
        OrgManager.CursorDataInfoInStruct info = OrgManager.getInstance().getCursorDataInfoInStruct(taskId);
        if(info != null){
            if(info.members != null){
                info.members.getCount();
            }
            if(info.nodes != null){
                info.nodes.getCount();
            }
        }

        return info;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( OrgManager.CursorDataInfoInStruct result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result != null){

            gridAdapter.changeCursor(result.members);
            departmentAdapter.changeCursor(result.nodes);
        }

    }

}
```

//OrgManager.java

```
public CursorDataInfoInStruct getCursorDataInfoInStruct(long structId){
        OrgStruct struct = getStruct(structId);
        if(null == struct && structId != 0) return null;

        CursorDataInfoInStruct info = new CursorDataInfoInStruct();
        info.parent = struct;
        info.nodes = getDb().rawQuery(SQL_QUERY_NODE_DATA_IN_SRUCT, new String[]{String.valueOf(structId)});
        info.members = getDb().rawQuery(SQL_QUERY_MEMBER_DATA_IN_SRUCT ,  new String[]{String.valueOf(structId)});

        return info;
    }
```

Class of info.members and info.nodes is Cursor.

When info.members has about 2000 rows , it will block my ui thread for about four second in my device.
I call cursor.getCount() in the work thread, but it doesn't help.

Comment: How exactly did you concluded that using `changeCursor()` is blocking the UI thread?

Comment: first.It will not block ui thread when data is about one hundred in cursor.And when data is about five hundreds , it will block few seconds.But when data is more than one thousand , it will cause ANR. Second.All codes to get data is in the method doinbackground.And in onPostExecute I do litte other thing except changeCursor().

Comment: @ZebulonLi Why call `.getCount()` at all if you're only going to ignore the return value?

Comment: @SK9 It's only trying LionKing's answer below.

Comment: How were got cursors dataInfo.members and dataInfo.nodes?
The impression that cursors info.members,info.nodes and dataInfo.members,dataInfo.nodes are different.
Try to measure the time of each method call.

Comment: @LionKing  Sorry. info is dataInfo actually.I omit some code and make the mistake. I copy the method for getting cursor data here.

Comment: @Zebulon Li Please try to measure the time of each method call

Answer (score 1):

See [Using Cursor with ListView adapter for a large amount of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330565/using-cursor-with-listview-adapter-for-a-large-amount-of-data)

When you use changeCursor it calls Cursor.getCount() - "this forces the query to be fully executed and the results counted".

I did so - in background thread prepare cursor and get it's length (extract data from db will execute here):

```
stopManagingCursor(cursor);
cursor = dbAdapter.getData(query);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
count = cursor.getCount();
```

in UI thread (onPostExecute) change cursor:

```
recordsAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
```

In this case change cursor don't freeze UI thread.

Comment: Thank your for your response , but it doesn't helps. My phone is Nexus S with 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old but it might be usefull for someone ,
I solved my issue  in a simple way :-)
Let's assume my query which i call from an asynctask on the doInBackground is something like that:

```
...
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    Cursor newCursor = getALLmyData();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Cursor oldCursor = adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
            if(oldCursor!=null){
            oldCursor.close();
        }
    }
    });
    ....

private Cursor getALLmyData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * FORM MY_HUGE_TABLE";
    return db.rawQuery(query, null, null);
}
```

In this case the adapter.swapCursor(newCursor); will block the UI for sevral seconds becase of the .getCount() methond in the adapter.
What I did is as simple as fast
I simple changed the query in that way

```
public Cursor getALLmyData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * FORM MY_HUGE_TABLE";
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null, null);
    Log.d(TAG," Rows:" +res.getCount());
    return res;
}
```

in that way the full query is executed in the doInBackground instead of the main UI while calling swapCursor(newCursor) because the res.getCount() do it :-)
now the swap is really fast!
Please note that swapaCursor returns the oldCursor in the adapter and you MUST close it!
Hope it helps!