# Android : Expandable ListView Adapter from Database / ContentProvider / ContentResolver

Tags: android, database, adapter, android-contentprovider, expandablelistview

I'm trying to build an Expandable ListView.

I have a Database with 3 tables, for the time being, from which I need to extract stuff (and update some, too). Also, i use my own Content Provider and the Activity's Content Resolver to interact with my DB. In the future, i'll add some SOAP calls to synchronize my locale DB to a remote DB, regarding the Virgil Dobjanschi's Rest Design Pattern (or at least, i'm gonna try...).

My 1st Question is : Which Adapter should I use for my ELV ?

I started with a BaseExpandableListAdapter but I noticed that I always had to make a query by myself to extract and update the datas. for example :

```
        EditText et;

        et = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.explist_qty);
        et.setOnClickListener(mController);

        Cursor cursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(
                MyContentProvider.getUri(QuantityTable.TABLE_QUANTITY), 
                new String[]{ QuantityTable.COLUMN_QUANTITY }, 
                QuantityTable.COLUMN_STOCK_ID +"=="+groupPosition, null, null);
        String qty = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow((QuantityTable.COLUMN_QUANTITY)));

        et.setText(qty);
```

I don't think this is the right choice since I need a Cursor for everything. That's why I looked for the CursorTreeAdapter but I red somewhere that it's often use to avoid Content Provider / Resolver pattern to be made. Now I'm definitely lost and I need your help.

For informations, my ELV displays a TextView as header, and a few EditTexts / Buttons as child. I need the buttons to update the EditText and the 2 Databases (locale with my Content Provider, and remote with SOAP calls).

Here comes my second question : How can I make my views to refresh itself regarding the locale DB ?

I've already heard about Observer/Observable design pattern but i'm not sure it can be done with databases, i may be wrong.

I'm learning Android so it's kinda hard for a noob like me to understand how everything goes and what are the good practices.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that fit perfectly what i wanted.

The adapter for the ELV is obviously a CursorTreeAdapter which is perfect when working with a database. I feed the adapter thanks to a Cursor Loader. I'm using the Activity Loader Manager and i init a Loader. My Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks, so i've the 3 methods onCreateLoader(), onLoadFinished(), and onLoaderReset().

In onCreateLoader(), I make a query thanks to my Content Resolver which is linked to a custom Content Provider, and i attach it to a custom CursorLoader (that i return) which listen to a particular URI. My Content Provider notify this URI if there is any change on the table, so the CursorLoader know it has to reload itself.

The onLoadFinished() simply set the current cursor to the adapter, and the onLoaderReset() simply set null to the adapter.

That way, everything work in a background thread, no UI freeze, and the content is refreshed automatically each time it needs.

There is a lot of work in there and it's hard to explain in a few lines. There are something like thousands lines of code so I can't copy/paste it there. I just came back to give my solution if it can help someone. Don't hesitate to ask me to explain something, i'll do my best to answer.

Comment: Would you able to help me out, with your solution, I am having a problem with simplecursortreeadapter. I have custom list view adapter which extends simple cursor tree adapter. All data is populated from the database, I have button on every list view item, when I tried to modify data with button click listview is loaded again, is there any way to modify the data without causing the all list to be created all over again.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible when working with Cursors. I am refreshing the whole list too but most of the time this isn't an issue because I don't have a lot of data to display. Maybe you could see for adding a "load more" system for your listview if you have a lot of data. This way you would only show the first rows, and you load the next ones dynamically as the user scrolls down the list. Refreshing it should be better as it shows only a few rows instead of all rows. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330565/using-cursor-with-listview-adapter-for-a-large-amount-of-data

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, after few days, and search on stackoverlow, i have come up with the solution below    


    }

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        final int productSubCategoryId = groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(DbVar.ID));
        Cursor childCursor = null;
        try {
            final String sortOrder = DbVar.PRODUCT_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
            final CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                    shoppingListFragment.getActivity(),
                    PGContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_SHOPPING_LIST_TABLE,
                    ShoppingListTable.FIELD_LIST,
                    "(" + DbVar.PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_ID + "=?)",
                    new String[]{ productSubCategoryId + ""}, sortOrder);
            cursorLoader.registerListener(0, this);
            childCursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
            childCursor.moveToFirst();

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return childCursor;
```